# How do I force matplotlib to write out the full form of the x-axis label, avoiding scientific notation?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've created a simple hexbin plot with matplotlib.pyplot.  I haven't changed any default settings.  My x-axis information ranges from 2003 to 2009, while the y values range from 15 to 35.  Rather than writing out 2003, 2004, etc., matplotlib collapses it into 0, 1, 2, ... + 2.003e+03.  Is there a simple way to force matplotlib to write out the full numbers?

Thanks,
Mark C.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can use the [`xticks` function](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks) to set string labels:

```
nums = arange(2003, 2010)
xticks(nums, (str(n) for n in nums))
```

**EDIT:** This is a better way:

```
gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%d'))
```

or something like that, anyway. (In older versions of Matplotlib the method was called `setMajorFormatter`.)

Comment: don't know from which version, but since Matplotlib 1.0 setMajorFormatter is set_major_formatter.

Comment: Or with full namespaces: matplotlib.pyplot.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%d'))

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677368/matplotlib-format-axis-offset-values-to-whole-numbers-or-specific-number, which suggests using [`ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False)`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter).