# Format axis offset-values to whole numbers or specific number

Tags: python, matplotlib, xticks, yticks

I have a matplotlib figure which I am plotting data that is always referred to as nanoseconds (1e-9).  On the y-axis, if I have data that is tens of nanoseconds, ie. 44e-9, the value on the axis shows as 4.4 with a +1e-8 as an offset.  Is there anyway to force the axis to show 44 with a +1e-9 offset?

The same goes for my x-axis where the axis is showing +5.54478e4, where I would rather it show an offset of +55447 (whole number, no decimal - the value here is in days).

I've tried a couple things like this:

```
p = axes.plot(x,y)
p.ticklabel_format(style='plain')
```

for the x-axis, but this doesn't work, though I'm probably using it incorrectly or misinterpreting something from the docs, can someone point me in the correct direction?

Thanks,
Jonathan

[image: Problem illustration]

---

I tried doing something with formatters but haven't found any solution yet...:

```
myyfmt = ScalarFormatter(useOffset=True)
myyfmt._set_offset(1e9)
axes.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(myyfmt)
```

and

```
myxfmt = ScalarFormatter(useOffset=True)
myxfmt.set_portlimits((-9,5))
axes.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(myxfmt)
```

On a side note, I'm actually confused as to where the 'offset number' object actually resides...is it part of the major/minor ticks?

Answer (score 104):

I had exactly the same problem, and these lines fixed the problem:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter

y_formatter = ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(y_formatter)
```

Comment: A one-liner would be: `ax.get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)`

Comment: for noobs like me dont forget the `from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter` for @Gonzalo 's code to work or simply use @Dataman 's solution above

Answer (score 38):

A much easier solution is to simply customize the tick labels. Take this example:

```
from pylab import *

# Generate some random data...
x = linspace(55478, 55486, 100)
y = random(100) - 0.5
y = cumsum(y)
y -= y.min()
y *= 1e-8

# plot
plot(x,y)

# xticks
locs,labels = xticks()
xticks(locs, map(lambda x: "%g" % x, locs))

# ytikcs
locs,labels = yticks()
yticks(locs, map(lambda x: "%.1f" % x, locs*1e9))
ylabel('microseconds (1E-9)')

show()
```

[image]

Notice how in the y-axis case, I multiplied the values by `1e9` then mentioned that constant in the y-label

---

**EDIT**

Another option is to fake the exponent multiplier by manually adding its text to the top of the plot:

```
locs,labels = yticks()
yticks(locs, map(lambda x: "%.1f" % x, locs*1e9))
text(0.0, 1.01, '1e-9', fontsize=10, transform = gca().transAxes)
```

---

**EDIT2**

Also you can format the x-axis offset value in the same manner:

```
locs,labels = xticks()
xticks(locs, map(lambda x: "%g" % x, locs-min(locs)))
text(0.92, -0.07, "+%g" % min(locs), fontsize=10, transform = gca().transAxes)
```

[image]

Comment: That was exactly what I did, at first. Unfortunately, I couldn't find an easy way to set/show the axis multiplier (other than explicitly putting it in the y-axis label, as you did.).  If you don't mind not having the axis multiplier label, this is the simpler way.  Either way, +1 from me.

Comment: @Joe Kington: you can add it manually as text... see the edit above :)

Comment: Great!  I'm going to try your approach with the labels for the x-axis.  I'll take the floor of the first x value, then remove it from every x-value and add a "+minxval" as a label.  I can't figure out how else to format the x-tick offset.  I'm fine with the magnitude of the offset, I just need for it to display as a non-exponential value.

Comment: Wow. Great job in showing how you can really take control of matplotlib and tweak it to your needs and really and some pizazz to your plots.

Comment: How do you change the fontsize of 1e-9 in the figure?

Comment: "Much easier". LOL. Matplotlib's API is really all over the place.

Answer (score 34):

You have to subclass `ScalarFormatter` to do what you need... `_set_offset` just adds a constant, you want to set `ScalarFormatter.orderOfMagnitude`. Unfortunately, manually setting `orderOfMagnitude` won't do anything, as it's reset when the `ScalarFormatter` instance is called to format the axis tick labels.  It shouldn't be this complicated, but I can't find an easier way to do exactly what you want...  Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter, FormatStrFormatter

class FixedOrderFormatter(ScalarFormatter):
    """Formats axis ticks using scientific notation with a constant order of 
    magnitude"""
    def __init__(self, order_of_mag=0, useOffset=True, useMathText=False):
        self._order_of_mag = order_of_mag
        ScalarFormatter.__init__(self, useOffset=useOffset, 
                                 useMathText=useMathText)
    def _set_orderOfMagnitude(self, range):
        """Over-riding this to avoid having orderOfMagnitude reset elsewhere"""
        self.orderOfMagnitude = self._order_of_mag

# Generate some random data...
x = np.linspace(55478, 55486, 100) 
y = np.random.random(100) - 0.5
y = np.cumsum(y)
y -= y.min()
y *= 1e-8

# Plot the data...
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y, 'b-')

# Force the y-axis ticks to use 1e-9 as a base exponent 
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FixedOrderFormatter(-9))

# Make the x-axis ticks formatted to 0 decimal places
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%0.0f'))
plt.show()
```

Which yields something like:
[image]

Whereas, the default formatting would look like:
[image]

Hope that helps a bit!

Edit: For what it's worth, I don't know where the offset label resides either... It would be  slightly easier to just manually set it, but I couldn't figure out how to do so...  I get the feeling that there has to be an easier way than all of this.  It works, though!

Comment: Thanks! Subclassing the ScalarFormatter works great!  But I guess I didn't clearly state what I wanted for the x-axis.  I would like to keep the offset for the x-axis, but format the value of the offset so it isn't shown as an exponent.

Comment: This is the only method that worked for me! Thanks :)

Answer (score 11):

Similar to Amro's answer, you can use FuncFormatter

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

# Generate some random data...
x = np.linspace(55478, 55486, 100) 
y = np.random.random(100) - 0.5
y = np.cumsum(y)
y -= y.min()
y *= 1e-8

# Plot the data...
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y, 'b-')

# Force the y-axis ticks to use 1e-9 as a base exponent 
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: ('%.1f')%(x*1e9)))
ax.set_ylabel('microseconds (1E-9)')

# Make the x-axis ticks formatted to 0 decimal places
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: '%.0f'%x))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 7):

Gonzalo's solution started working for me after having added `set_scientific(False)`:

```
ax=gca()
fmt=matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False)
fmt.set_scientific(False)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)
```

Answer (score 7):

As has been pointed out in the comments and [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29535832/1143274), the offset may be switched off globally, by doing the following:

```
matplotlib.rcParams['axes.formatter.useoffset'] = False
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that a more elegant way is to use the ticker formatter. Here is an example for both xaxis and yaxis:

```
from pylab import *
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator, FormatStrFormatter

majorLocator   = MultipleLocator(20)
xFormatter = FormatStrFormatter('%d')
yFormatter = FormatStrFormatter('%.2f')
minorLocator   = MultipleLocator(5)


t = arange(0.0, 100.0, 0.1)
s = sin(0.1*pi*t)*exp(-t*0.01)

ax = subplot(111)
plot(t,s)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(majorLocator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xFormatter)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(yFormatter)

#for the minor ticks, use no labels; default NullFormatter
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minorLocator)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is _how to specify the offset_ and/or the _factor used in scientific notation_.

Comment: @nordev Even if my answer does not specifically answer the question it still gives a hint. The message is that you can chose another formatter and get what you want instead of a date from my example. In the scientific world Julian day is the norm, or you can use date as in my example. What I was trying to suggest is that a different approach can be taken. Sometimes a question may be asked because the person doesn't have a better idea at the moment. Alternative solutions should not be discarded or treated with disrespect. All in all I did not deserve the -1 vote.

Answer (score 2):

For the second part, without manually resetting all the ticks again, this was my solution:

```
class CustomScalarFormatter(ScalarFormatter):
    def format_data(self, value):
        if self._useLocale:
            s = locale.format_string('%1.2g', (value,))
        else:
            s = '%1.2g' % value
        s = self._formatSciNotation(s)
        return self.fix_minus(s)
xmajorformatter = CustomScalarFormatter()  # default useOffset=True
axes.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(xmajorformatter)
```

obviously you can set the format string to whatever you want.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't investigated how to set the multiplier as the first part of your question states.

Answer (score 0):

[Joe Kington's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3679918/13688160) doesn't work for me somehow. But I find that matplotlib can do this natively with [set_powerlimits](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter.set_powerlimits) now:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter

# Generate some random data...
x = np.linspace(55478, 55486, 100) 
y = np.random.random(100) - 0.5
y = np.cumsum(y)
y -= y.min()
y *= 1e-8

# Plot the data...
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y, 'b-')

# Force the y-axis ticks to use 1e-9 as a base exponent
y_formatter = ScalarFormatter()
y_formatter.set_powerlimits((-9, -9))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(y_formatter)

# Make the x-axis ticks formatted to 0 decimal places
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False))
plt.show()
```