# yaxis range display using absolute values rather than offset values

Tags: python, matplotlib, yaxis

I have the following range of numpy data (deltas of usec timestamps):

```
array([ 4.312,  4.317,  4.316,  4.32 ,  4.316,  4.316,  4.319,  4.317,
    4.317,  4.316,  4.318,  4.316,  4.318,  4.316,  4.318,  4.317,
    4.317,  4.317,  4.316,  4.317,  4.318,  4.316,  4.318,  4.316,
    4.318,  4.316,  4.317,  4.317,  4.318,  4.316,  4.317,  4.317,
    4.317,  4.317,  4.317,  4.316,  4.319,  4.315,  4.319,  4.315,
    4.319,  4.315,  4.316,  4.319,  4.317,  4.317,  4.317,  4.318,
    4.315,  4.317,  4.317,  4.317,  4.319,  4.314,  4.32 ,  4.315,
    4.317,  4.318,  4.315,  4.318,  4.317,  4.317,  4.317,  4.316,
    4.317,  4.318,  4.317,  4.317,  4.317,  4.315,  4.319,  4.317,
    4.315,  4.319,  4.316,  4.318,  4.318,  4.315,  4.318,  4.317,
    4.317,  4.321])
```

When I plot with matplotlib.pyplot:

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 plt.plot( deltas ) 
 plt.show()
```

I get the following plot. Why is the Y-axis being scaled that way? How can I get the Y-axis to be labeled as the data, not an offset of the data?  Sometimes the plot is the "+4.nnn" sometimes it isn't (depending on the data range?).

Plotted "strangely":
[image: Plotted Badly]

Plotted "correctly":
[image: Plotted Correctly]

Answer (score 48, accepted):

set useOffset to False:

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me anymore in MPL 1.3.0. It says that this now only works with a ScalarFormatter. So the short answer in here solved it for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677368/matplotlib-format-axis-offset-values-to-whole-numbers-or-specific-number

Comment: `ax.get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)`

Answer (score 11):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29535832/1143274) suggested disabling the offset as a global setting, which worked for me:

```
matplotlib.rcParams['axes.formatter.useoffset'] = False
```

Comment: I like this option. I have come across very few instances where I would like to make use of the offset setting.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticks())
```

Although I like @HYRY's answer better.

Comment: This answer may easily lead to completely wrong outcomes. Never set the labels without fixing the positions as well!! Better use any of the other answers.