# Remove axis label offset by default

Tags: python, matplotlib, x-axis

I've read other questions here offering

```
plt.gca().get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
```

as a way to remove axis offsets on the current plot, but is there any way to do this by default? I don't see anything in the matplotlibrc file that seems helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to do it. It is defined in the source file of `ticker.py`, line 353:

```
def __init__(self, useOffset=True, useMathText=None, useLocale=None):
    # useOffset allows plotting small data ranges with large offsets: for
    # example: [1+1e-9,1+2e-9,1+3e-9] useMathText will render the offset
    # and scientific notation in mathtext

    self.set_useOffset(useOffset)
```

as a default parameter values. So the default is `True`.

You can modify the source, of course.

Comment: This answer is wrong and editing your installation in-place is an extremely bad idea.

Answer (score 16):

[In 2013](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2401) a boolean matplotlibrc parameter called `axes.formatter.useoffset` was added, which can switch off the offset.

For example like this:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['axes.formatter.useoffset'] = False
```

Comment: Could you add a line showing us matplotlib perma-noobs how it would be used? Thanks!  (something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9303922/3904031)).

Comment: @uhoh `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcParams['axes.formatter.useoffset'] = False` is equally possible.

Comment: Does not work when using subplot2grid, parameter just goes ignored.