# Hide tick labels and offset in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have two subplots that share the same x-axis. I removed the xticklabels of the upper subplot, but the offset "1e7" remains visible. How can I hide it?

Here is the code I used :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure()
s1 = plt.subplot(2,1,1)
s1.plot(np.arange(0,1e8,1e7),np.arange(10))
s1.tick_params(axis="x", labelbottom=False)

s2 = plt.subplot(2,1,2, sharex=s1)
s2.plot(np.arange(0,1e8,1e7),np.arange(10))
```

I also tried `s1.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)`, but it did nothing and I also tried `s1.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_powerlimits((-9,9))` but it impacted also the lower suplot.

Comment: For hiding the offset: Did you try `axes.formatter.useoffset`already? Cf. [matplotlib remove axis label offset by default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171064/matplotlib-remove-axis-label-offset-by-default) the answer of @Christoph

Comment: I tried `s1.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)`, but it did nothing and I also tried `s1.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_powerlimits((-9,9))` but it impacted also the lower suplot.

Comment: Everyone loves these best previous attempts (and why they did not work) inside the questions, as comments are somewhat inaccessible ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to use [`plt.subplots`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots) to create the subplots, and use `sharex=True` as an option there. This automatically turns off all `ticklabels` and the `offset_text` from the top subplot. From the docs:

> sharex : string or bool
>
> If True, the X axis will be shared amongst all subplots. If True and
>   you have multiple rows, the x tick labels on all but the last row of
>   plots will have visible set to False

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, (s1, s2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)
s1.plot(np.arange(0,1e8,1e7),np.arange(10))

s2.plot(np.arange(0,1e8,1e7),np.arange(10))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I finally find the answer on https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4445. I need to add the following line to my code :

```
plt.setp(s1.get_xaxis().get_offset_text(), visible=False)
```