# How to prevent scientific notation in matplotlib boxplot (when ScalarFormatter is not used)?

Tags: matplotlib

```
boxplot(df.dmass)
ylabel(r'$\Delta M$')
xlabel('peakMz - exactmass')
```

[image]

The values are all around -1, but you cannot guess that from that unfortunate notation.

`gca().ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)` does not work here.

Comment: "does not work" is never a useful problem description. What happens when you use it?

Comment: AttributeError: This method only works with the ScalarFormatter

Comment: Oh yes, because the xaxis doesn't use a ScalarFormatter. So you need to do it only for the y axis I suppose, `gca().ticklabel_format(axis="y", useOffset=False)`

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You can turn off the offset globally, if that is what you want?

Comment: That would be great!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29535832/4124317

Answer (score 0):

So, according to `ImportanceOfBeingErnest` the offset needs to be deactivated axis specific:

```
gca().ticklabel_format(axis="y", useOffset=False)
```

for the y-axis.