# matplotlib Axis not showing full value

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

when I run my code the Y axis is not showing full value as seen in picture below
[image]

I know I am missing something to do with my Axis not sure where? my code for Axis is below

```
ax.tick_params (axis='y', which='major', labelsize=5)
ax.tick_params (axis='x', which='major', labelsize=5)
ax.set_xlim(BBox[0],BBox[1])
ax.set_ylim(BBox[2],BBox[3])
```

I am aware that I can set both Y and X the same but the X axis is fine not the Y

Comment: What do you mean by the Y axis not showing the full value? What was it supposed to be showing instead?

Comment: You could [turn off the axis offset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29535832/3279716). `mpl.rcParams['axes.formatter.useoffset'] = False`

Comment: if you see by the Y axis it has +5.17000000e1, well the y axis start with 51.69514 and ends with  51.70101 as my Latitude and the X axis starts with  -3.33537 and ends with -3.34953 for Longitude

Answer (score 1):

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['axes.formatter.useoffset'] = False
```