# Plot in python but it changed my y values automaticlly in the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

When I wanna plot my data in python, it shows modified values of my y-values instead of original data.

[image]

As can be seen in the plot, it subtracts 1.455e2(which is written beside the y axis) from my original data and I wanna show the original data in my plot.
Here's my script about the plot:

```
plt.xlabel("H(Oe)")
plt.ylabel("R*E-3(dBm)")

plt.plot(h_1,r_2,linestyle="-",linewidth=1,label="2.50_GHz")
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.grid(color="k", linestyle=":")
plt.savefig("0_deg_2.50_GHz_R.png", dpi=300,bbox_inches = 'tight')
plt.show()
```

And actually it does show the original y-values for some other data files, I'm using the exactly same script but for this one it always shows the modified values.
Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: you don't have a `plt.plot(h_1, your_modified_values...)` above this code, do you? or the modified values in `r_2`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303728/matplotlib-yaxis-range-display-using-absolute-values-rather-than-offset-values

Answer (score 3):

This is *not* scientific notation but is known as an offset (hence the `+` before the number). The original values can be seen by adding the offset to all of the values.

You can prevent an offset being used as:

```
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
```

Comment: Yep, this is correct. I thought I saw scientific notation but it is not the case.

Comment: It's the ```e```: always makes me immediately think of scientific notation too!