# How to use exact values of axes' using matplotlib in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, precision, axes

I have taken some graphics using matplotlib in python. But, y values cannot be understood easily. The picture is given below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvcEj.png)

How can I change these coordinate scripts. How can I use function values without degree on top of the figure

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303728/matplotlib-yaxis-range-display-using-absolute-values-rather-than-offset-values