# Force pyplot to show actual axis values

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am using Python and Pyplot to produce a plot. The y axis of the plot is generated automatically, and works fine.

If the range is small however, the y axis will produce values such as:

```
0.00005,  
0.00010,  
0.00015,  
0.00020,  
0.00025,  
0.00030,
```

and then at the top of the axis, will say:

```
+1.543e-1
```

I would prefer that it just explicitly shows the values:

```
0.15435  
0.15440  
0.15445  
0.15450  
0.15455  
0.15460
```

Could someone tell me how to do this please?

Comment: Take a look at the [ticker api](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html), and perhaps this [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/major_minor_demo1.html#pylab-examples-major-minor-demo1)

Comment: there is a PR in the works to be able to set this as an rcparam, should be in 1.4.

Comment: for completeness, https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2401

Comment: Nice @tcaswell. I also would like that offset feature `off` by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I think I found the total solution:

Here is a quick plot that recreates your problem:

```
plot((0.15435,0.15440,0.15445,0.15450,0.15455,0.15460),(0.15435,0.15440,0.15445,0.15450,0.15455,0.15460))
```

The following code (similar to how it was as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6654046/30213)) should adjust the ticker like you want:

```
y_formatter = matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False)
gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(y_formatter)
```