# matplotlib: bold tick labels with scientific notation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to have bold tick labels with LaTeX-fonts in matplotlib. A sample plot can be found here:
[sample plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ou91L.png)

The code I am using:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f=plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = f.add_subplot(111)
x_data = [x for x in range(0, 200)]
y_data = [pow(x,6) for x in x_data]


plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='serif')
plt.rc('font', size=24)
plt.rc('font', weight='bold')
plt.grid(True)


p3, = plt.plot(x_data,y_data,'g',linewidth = 7,ls='dashed',markersize=8,markeredgewidth=8)

ax.ticklabel_format(axis='y', style='sci', scilimits=(-2,2))
mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter(useMathText = True)

plt.show()
```

The problem is, I would like to have the 1e13 in the upper corner to be displayed as $10^13$ as it would be if I leave out

```
mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter(useMathText = True)
```

but then it is not in bold font. Is there any way to do this? I know that I could to all kind of tweaking with the original data by hand, but I would be totally happy to have an automatic solution.

And related to this question, I found the following thread:

[matplotlib: format axis offset-values to whole numbers or specific number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677368/matplotlib-format-axis-offset-values-to-whole-numbers-or-specific-number)

There Joe Kington wrote a class FixedOrderFormatter(ScalarFormatter), which allows to change the power from 1e13 to 1e14, for example. Is there maybe even a way to combine the FixedOrderFormatter with the scientific notation to be $10^14$ with bold font instead of 1e14?