# How can I make matplotlib not "merge" axis labels?

Tags: matplotlib

How can I force matplotlib to not "merge" y-axis labels?  For example, if I've got y-axis ticks at `1`, `1.01`, `1.02`, etc.,  matplotlib likes to show `0`, `0.01`, `0.02` with a `+1` in the upper left corner.  An example showing this behavior underlined in red is below:

[image: This is some example behavior I don't want]

How can I disable this behavior?  I don't know what it's called, so I don't know what to Google to shut it off.

Comment: I believe this is what you're looking for: [axis offsest values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677368/matplotlib-format-axis-offset-values-to-whole-numbers-or-specific-number).

Comment: Thank you.  I would be happy to accept that if you'll submit it as an answer.

Comment: I appreciate the offer, but it's not like I did anything new/clever to deserve the points.  Plus, sometimes it takes a bit before you find the "actual" name of behavior.  Cheers!

Comment: As you like, but I'm not of the opinion that one needs to provide clever answers-- only answers.  Thank you again.

Comment: Consider answering your own question and accepting that answer in due time. That'll make it more useful for future visitors - especially should the comments get purged