# Matplotlib: plot data to one set of axes while displaying another

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using `matplotlib.pyplot` I want to plot my data relative to a certain set of axes but then I want to have my axis show a different range of values without affecting the portion of my data that is shown.

To be specific, I have a 1000x1000 grid of data I am plotting with `pyplot.imshow()`; however, I only want my axes to run from -2 to 2 (both x and y axes) while still showing the whole 1000x1000 grid.  If possible, I would like to hard code these values (-2 and 2) as being the limits of my axis rather than using some sort of rescaling from the 1000x1000 grid to the new axes.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

array = np.loadtxt("output.dat",unpack=True)
im = plt.imshow(array,cmap='hot')
plt.colorbar(im)
```

Comment: this question might be of use to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677368/matplotlib-format-axis-offset-values-to-whole-numbers-or-specific-number

Comment: @paintedcones that helps but what I would like to do is basically hard code the axes to values I set rather than using some sort of axis rescaler like I see in the examples in the link you posted.

Comment: Have you tried `plt.ylim(-2,2)` `plt.xlim(-2,2)`?

Comment: @N1B4 That zooms in on that portion of the grid rather than scaling the axes while still showing the whole grid.

Comment: Do you just want to scale all values in the gridded data to be within 2 to -2?  That's just normalizing the data to (-1,1) and then adding 1 to all grid points.

Comment: @N1B4, that's not what I'm trying to do.  I want the spatial extent of the grid to be within 2 and -2, not the values of the grid itself.

Answer (score 1):

Just found an answer which works specifically for `plt.imshow()`.  The `extent` parameter. Replacing

```
im = plt.imshow(array,cmap='hot')
```

in my original code example with

```
im = plt.imshow(array,cmap='hot',extent=(-2,2,-2,2))
```

will take care of things.

Comment: @paintedcones It does work.  If you look, the question asker and the answerer are the same person.  I wouldn't have posted an answer to my own question if the answer didn't work!

Comment: Yes, I know.. but if this is the correct answer, you should press "accept answer" so future SO visitors know.

Comment: @paintedcones, when you answer your own question you can't accept the answer for two days.