# Use matplotlib to set the x-axis

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following `masterResult.csv` file:

```
DATE,    DATASET,       BUILD        Col1   Col2 Col3
5/3/16,  Amazon,        1001         1113   344  169
5/3/16,  Amazon,        1002         1113   344  169
5/3/16,  Amazon,        1005         1113   344  169
5/3/16,  Amazon,        1006         1113   344  169
```

I would like to draw a graph using `matplotlib`.

My code is:

```
per_data=genfromtxt('masterResult.csv',delimiter=',',names=True)
for name in per_data.dtype.names[2:]:    
    plt.plot(per_data['BUILD'], per_data[name], label=name)
```

But that gave me: [image: graph for masterResult.csv]

And the x-axis range is not right. How to make it so x-axis range is from 1001 ~ 1006?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Import**:

You can use different [parameters](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy.genfromtxt) to optimize the import:

```
data = np.genfromtxt('masterResult.csv', skip_header=1, usecols=(2,3,4,5), dtype="i8", autostrip=True)

print data
# [[1001 1113  344  169]
#  [1002 1113  344  169]
#  [1005 1113  344  169]
#  [1006 1113  344  169]]
```

**Plot**:

Finally a simple plot of the data:

```
draw = plt.plot(data[:,0], data[:,range(1,4)], '--o')
plt.legend(draw, ('Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'))
plt.xlabel("Build")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! But for my x-axis, how do I add 1001,~ 1005 as x label? and there will be more attached to the file, we plan to run this  many times, and I need to show the actual build number.

Comment: OH I get it, the +1.001e3 is the floating number. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly, otherwise you can [format the labels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677368/matplotlib-format-axis-offset-values-to-whole-numbers-or-specific-number).

Answer (score 2):

The simple way to set the xaxis, if your data were right, would be `plt.xlim(1001,1006)`, but that's not the problem.

The reason why your x axis is wrong in the first place is because your data file is not a correct csv file. The BUILD and subsequent columns aren't separated by commas, which confuses numpy. If you take a look at per_data directly, you'll see BUILD isn't set to a number at all. You either need to add commas consistently, or have it as tab/space separated data. And in general, if things look very wrong, it can be useful to look at your array directly instead of just plotting it.