# Matplotlib: Move the multiplier below the x-axis to the top

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to find a way to move the little multiplier below the x-axis to the top. I have a plot with two x-axis and the multiplier of the top axis is placed below the bottom x-axis, which I find confusing.

Here is a small example:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

fig = plt.figure(num=None,figsize=(15, 2.5), dpi=300)
gs = mpl.gridspec.GridSpec(1,1)
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[0,0])
ax1 = ax2.twiny()
ax1.grid(False)

ax1.set_xlim(0,10000000)
ax2.set_xlim(0,1000000)
ax1.set_ylim([0,100])
ax2.set_ylim([0,100])
plt.show()
```

Now, if you change `ax2.set_xlim(0,1000000)` to `ax2.set_xlim(0,100000000)`, then both multipliers are placed below the bottom x-axis. Maybe it is also possible to prevent the multiplier from overlapping with the x-axis tick labels?

My problem with researching this is that I have no idea how this 'multiplier' is actually called.

Comment: In [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677368/matplotlib-format-axis-offset-values-to-whole-numbers-or-specific-number) you'll find a lot about this offset/multiplier. Maybe it helps.