# Cancelling the offset on an axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

Just noticed this nuance when I editing my works.

Previously, the matplotlib would look like this:

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5]
y=[4,5,5,2,1]
plot(x,y,'-')
```

[image]

But after recent upgrade I believe, the there are offset, which would return like this

[image]

It's a little bit unncessary from what I seen now. I want to know

1. If this offset is a good practice in data visualization? If so, I'll leave it as it is.
2. How to cancel out this offset?

I can manually restore the limit by `plt.gca().set_xlim([1, 5])`, but that wouldn't scale if I have another 20 plots. I googled around and didn't find too much info on this.

Comment: have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677368/matplotlib-format-axis-offset-values-to-whole-numbers-or-specific-number

Comment: @putonspectacles Thanks! But I thought there should be an API or whatever... That answer looks like an overkill.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest that's the anwer! thanks!

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest But still, I want to know the discussion of it, if it is really a good practice that I do not understand? Maybe I should post that question somewhere else?

Comment: I agree that SO is probably not the best place to discuss whether this margin is a good data visualization technique. My personal opinon is: It doesn't really matter as long as you keep it consistent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In matplotlib v2.0.x, the default axes margin has changed, from 0 to 0.05, which is the value controlling the whitespace around your data on the axes. See [here](http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/users/dflt_style_changes.html#auto-limits) for more on the reasoning behind this change.

There are several ways to revert to the previous behaviour.

1) To reset `margins` to 0 for a single Axes instance:

```
plt.margins(0)
```

or

```
ax.margins(0)
```

2) To reset `margins` to 0 for all plots in a script, use `rcParams` and set this at the top of your script:

```
plt.rcParams['axes.autolimit_mode'] = 'round_numbers'
plt.rcParams['axes.xmargin'] = 0.
plt.rcParams['axes.ymargin'] = 0.
```

3) To change the default value for all plots on a machine, modify your the `matplotlibrc` file to include these lines:

```
axes.autolimit_mode: round_numbers
axes.xmargin        : 0.
axes.ymargin        : 0.
```

Note that to use method (1) and truly get the old behaviour, you may also need to set `plt.rcParams['axes.autolimit_mode'] = 'round_numbers'`.

Comment: Understood, I'd say that the reason I'm feeling awkaward is that it's mixing with seaborn. If there aren't grid line, the plot would look much better.

Answer (score 0):

Guess whether its good practice is a bit of a discussion. It somehow suggest that your plot continues (but you just show a window of it), so if your plot is only defined in this region having an offset would make sense. If it actually continues but you just plot this part, then it's logical to remove it.

The scalable approach is

```
 plt.gca().set_xlim([np.min(x), np.max(x)])
```

Comment: It would still be quite a trouble if I plot several lines or other element in one figure.