# How to read weird axis units from matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJRf0.png)So this is a histogram of MCMC run. The prior mean is at 29.89(if you don't know what MCMC is, I am expecting the histogram mean to be around this), but the x-axis unit has this label `(1e-7 + 29.89)`. So I am wondering, when the graph says `x=2`, does it mean `x=2*1e-7 + 29.89`? or `x=1e-7 + 20.00`?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [matplotlib: format axis offset-values to whole numbers or specific number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677368/matplotlib-format-axis-offset-values-to-whole-numbers-or-specific-number)

Comment: It means `x=2 * 1e-7 + 29.89`.