# How to manually set axis offset with custom tick labels?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, xticks

Consider the plot below. Both axis have custom labels, to label the rows and columns in an `imshow`-plot. The problem now is that the y-axis has very large values. Ideally I'd like to manually set an axis-offset (i.e. on top of the axis somethng like `1e5`) such that the ticks are only show a smaller number. How can I achieve that?

There was a solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6654046/2913106) but it does *not* work in this case, as we do not have a `ScalarFormatter` due to the custom labels:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
s = 10000000
x, y = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5], [2*s, 3*s, 5*s, 7*s]
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = np.random.rand(x.shape[0], x.shape[1])
plt.imshow(z)
plt.gca().set_yticks(range(len(y[..., 0])))
plt.gca().set_xticks(range(len(x[0, ...])))
plt.gca().set_yticklabels(y[..., 0])
plt.gca().set_xticklabels(x[0, ...])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter.set_offset_string()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter.set_offset_string) like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
s = 100000 # 1e+05
x = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
original_y = [20000000, 30000000, 50000000, 70000000]
y = [oy / s for oy in original_y]
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = np.random.rand(x.shape[0], x.shape[1])
plt.imshow(z)
plt.gca().set_yticks(range(len(y[..., 0])))
plt.gca().set_xticks(range(len(x[0, ...])))
plt.gca().set_yticklabels(y[..., 0])
plt.gca().set_xticklabels(x[0, ...])
plt.gca().yaxis.get_major_formatter().set_offset_string('{:.0e}'.format(s))
plt.show()
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can just manually place a label using `ax.text()`:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = 10000000

x, y = np.array([1, 1, 2, 3, 5]), s * np.array([2, 3, 5, 7])
z = np.random.rand(y.size, x.size)

ax = plt.subplot()
ax.imshow(z)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(y)))
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(x)))
ax.set_yticklabels(y / s)
ax.set_xticklabels(x)

# the position here is given in pixel coordinates
ax.text(-0.5, -0.55, f"{s:.0e}")

plt.show()
```

I hope this helps!